# How to tell if any users are logged on to a local mac or not, or uptime, or some daemon listening on a port?

Tags: macos, mac, remote

On a Mac (OS 10.13) Within my LAN, is there a way to tell whether another similar Mac has anyone logged in, or how long it's been up?  I have a headless mac that sometimes spontaneously reboots and I want to be able to monitor for this from another machine. If it happens, it will sit there at the login screen and I could detect that by the fact that no one is logged in. Or is there another way to detect that?  Maybe by the absence of some light-weight network service that should only be present if the user has logged on? What can I have it run as part of the login sequence that would be visible externally (something that listens on a port)?

Answer (score 0):

The first part, to see the status you could use `ssh` (aka "remote login" in mac-speak), run `uptime` to see how long it's been running, and `who` to see whom is logged in.

```
myuser@machine: ssh fredrik@viggen
Last login: Sat Feb  6 10:55:10 2021 from 10.1.66.37
fredrik@viggen:~$ who
fredrik     console  Feb  3 07:56
fredrik     ttys000  Feb  3 08:05
fredrik     ttys008  Feb  6 10:55   (10.1.66.37)
fredrik@viggen:~$ uptime
10:58  up 3 days,  3:03, 7 users, load averages: 2.68 2.33 2.29
fredrik@viggen:~$
```

"console" is graphical login, and "ttys000" is local terminal and the "ttys008" is a remote login as shown by the IP address.

Notification if a system is rebooted is more advanced and there are multiple ways of doing it. You could have a simple script that sends you an alert over a messenger (telegram or whatnot), IFTTT, pushover notifcation, send an email etc.

I would personally use a script to notify my phone via Telegram with a simple script. First, download [telegram-bash](https://github.com/fabianonline/telegram.sh), then I would put it in crontab (crontab -e), like this `@rebooot /path/to/telegram -t 123456:AbcDefGhi-JklMnoPrw -c 12345 "Hello, World."`

Comment: Thank you!!  1) is there a way to script the act of logging in via ssh (provide password), send the who and uptime commands via ssh, and collect the output, into my script?  2) does the cronttab @reboot method work after a system first comes up, or as it's being rebooted?